# Zend Framework2 and Oracle: Can not insert BLOB data in table

Tags: oracle, zend-framework2

I tried to insert BLOB data into a column in Oracle database through Zend Framework but its not working.

I can do it from core PHP code with oci connection but cant find solution for same in Zend Framework.

Can anyone provide some links to solve this issue?

Comment: Did you find any solution? if yes please share. I'm also facing this problem.